# Increase thickness of line in SCNGeometry

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have created a line but I'm not able to increase the thickness of it.

Is there something with `firstMaterial` that I can use to increase the thickness of my line?

Here you are my functions:

```
func getDrawnLineFrom(pos1: SCNVector3, toPos2: SCNVector3) -> SCNNode {

        let line = lineFrom(vector: pos1, toVector: toPos2)
        let lineInBetween1 = SCNNode(geometry: line)
        line.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents  = UIColor.blue

        return lineInBetween1
    }

    func lineFrom(vector vector1: SCNVector3, toVector vector2: SCNVector3) -> SCNGeometry{

        let indices: [Int32] = [0, 1]
        let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: [vector1, vector2])
        let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .line)


        return SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not helping at all...

Comment: Because you can't, at least not with the line primitive type, basically all alternatives are discussed or linked in the thread above, thats why I marked it as duplicate

Comment: Uh! Thank you ! I have just red that maybe can be useful use the cylinder

Answer (score 0):

What kind of geometry is it? `SCNPlane` and `SCNBox` have `width` and `height` properties that you can use to specify lenght and thickness of a line.
If it's `SCNShape` you can define the thickness on the path you use to create it.

Comment: Updated the question! Hope that you will be able to help me!

Comment: @PietroMessineo Any solution?

Comment: @HassanRiaz Unfortunately no solution.